# Wordpress, foreach inside foreach, duplicated info

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, duplicates

I need some help with solving duplicating problem. To deal:

I have 2 filed custom meta

[image: 2 filed custom meta]

It displays this way :

[image: only 2 image placed]

Only 2 image placed, but it duplicate `<li>`.

First and third `<li>` is only video, second and fourth works fine, looks like this :

[image]

```
foreach($slider_xml->childNodes as $slider){
$test_test = get_post_meta(9,'test_1', false);
foreach($test_test as $test_test){
echo '<li class="img-vid-slide">';
echo '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'. $test_test . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 
}
echo '<div class="img-slide" >';
if($link_type == 'Lightbox'){
$image_full_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(find_xml_value($slider, 'image'), 'full');
echo '<a href="' . $image_full_url[0] . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto[flexgal]" title=""  >';
}else if($link_type != 'No Link'){
echo '<a href="' . $link . '" >';
}
echo '<img class="'. $i .'" src="' . $image_url[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '" />';
echo '</div>';
if( !empty($title) ){
echo '<div class="flex-caption gdl-slider-caption">';
echo '<div class="gdl-slider-title">' . $title . '</div>';
echo '<div class="slider-title-bar"></div>';
echo $caption;
echo '</div>'; // flex-caption
}
if($link_type != 'No Link'){
echo '</a>';
}
echo '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution.

Filed custom fields: prntscr.com/7oqqvt

I named them like "name_1","name_2"..."name_4".
$i is equal of last nubmer in custom field.

Result on screen: prntscr.com/7oqsaw

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 3):
foreach( $slider_xml->childNodes as $slider ){
// ======= SAME AS FIRST ====== //  
$test_test = get_post_meta(9,'test_'. $i .'', true);    
echo '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'. $test_test . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; 
echo '<div class="img-slide" >';
if($link_type == 'Lightbox'){
// ======= SAME AS FIRST ====== //
}
echo '</li>';
$i++;       
}       
endwhile;
```

Works fine for me, do what i searching for!

Thanks, Greg, for a little hint, but i go for "while" instead of "for"! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the a foreach inside a foreach loop. It a function problem. 
Use the alternative "for" loop instead of the double foreach.

Comment: Hi, Greg! Thanks for respond. I'm sorry for my nonunderstanding. Don't realise how to do "for" in way like "foreach" works. If you can, some little hint... can't see same implementation while serfing